# POST data PHP cURL LOOP

Tags: php, curl

Mornin', How to post data with php curl and do loops ? i've stuck in here... the code doesn't work to loop POST data...

Here's my code :

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$conn) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}else{
    mysql_select_db('psv');
}

$query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_first_name != ''";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domain.com/user/register");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $r=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    "user_first_name=$r[2]&user_last_name=$r[3]&user_email=$r[4]&user_password=$r[5]&user_phone=0$r[6]&user_address=(value)");
}
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Any advice ?

I've changed my code like this, but doesn't do loops :

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$conn) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}else{
    mysql_select_db('passionville');
}

$query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_first_name != ''";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domain.com/user/register");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{
   $r=mysql_fetch_row($result);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    "user_first_name=$r[2]&user_last_name=$r[3]&user_email=$r[4]&user_password=$r[5]&user_phone=0$r[6]&user_address=(value)");
}
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: you are incrementing $i in your loop twice. You don't need it at the bottom.

Comment: `$r` is undefined, so should produce errors. Turn error reporting on and start from there

Comment: I would advise collecting the data from MySQL first and then POST it all at once. Also take a look at `http_build_query()`

Comment: the recordset is based upon `$result` - rather than `$r`

Comment: What should i do then ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Functions are deprecated and should not be used. Will provide similar MySQLi answer.

Separate your actions a bit. Collect the data from MySQL, and then build your post data.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'psv');
if (!$conn) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_first_name != ''";
$missing_names = array();
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
    // Assume you will have more than one row in the recordset
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $missing_names[] = $r;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    $err = mysqli_error($conn);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    die("SQL Error: $err\r\n";);
}

$results = array();
foreach($missing_names as $r) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domain.com/user/register");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($r));
    $results[] = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

So let's assume your Query has 3 results. They will be stored in the `$missing_names` array. You iterate over the array and post the data from each row. There are methods for persisting the connection or doing multiple posts, yet I think this is a better method. If there is an error or you expect results, you can check for `FALSE` in the `$results` array. You'll also know how many times it ran by the count of `$results`. You have return transfer set to true, so you must be expecting some return data.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 10

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_asso() in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 12

Comment: you've mising 'c' in mysql_fetch_assoc and give a new error : Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 15

Comment: Reviewed and edited. Check it out, test, and let me know.

Comment: Showed nothing... if success it will be show a json responses {"st":1,"msg":""}

Comment: Thanks so much dude... remove curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); solved my problem...